Estimation of a sum by an integral in Shor's algorithm
I am reading Peter W. Shor's original paper on his algorithm for integer factorisation.
On p.17 of the paper he is trying estimate a sum by an integral. He claimed that the expression inside the absolute value in (5.7) is equal to the expression in (5.8), an integral plus a big O notation:

$O(\frac{\lfloor(q-k-1)/r\rfloor}{q}(\exp(2\pi i\{rc\}_q/q) -1))$

I don't understand why the function inside the big O is of this form.
I tried to draw a curve on the plane and compare the area under the curve and area of rectangles each with width 1 to obtain this error term, but failed.
Moreover, the writer further mentioned that

If $|\{rc\}_q| ≤ r/2$ , the error term in the above expression is easily seen to be bounded by $O(1/q)$.

How can we see this?
